# Ubuntu freezes and the cursor becomes an X

Tags: 18.04

I have been running Ubuntu and doing some stuff with terminal when it just froze and the cursor turns to a X and nothing can be clicked or anything. It happens at random times. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Specs:

```
GTX 1060
Intel Core i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS
Graphics Driver: nvidia-driver-390
```

Comment: Please [edit] and post hardware specifications, namely graphics card and drivers (if you installed).

Comment: By "latest... drivers" which version do you mean exactly? And how have you installed it?

Comment: I installed it through software and updates menu.

Comment: Would you please open Additional Drivers again and tell us the number version that is in use? Thank you.

Comment: I am using nvidia-driver-390.

Comment: Ok, that may not be the best for a GTX1060 (but is indeed the latest available in 18.04 repositories). I suggest adding the Graphics drivers PPA then at the Additional Drivers newer version should appear, select and install 418 or 430.

Comment: You can try `prime-select intel` and reboot. This will turn off Nvidia card in Linux. Performance will be fine for normal users. If error recurs you know it's not Nvidia priblem. And focus attention elsewhere.